# How to use Webworker Threads (nodejs) and wait for Request function to get data and return before continuing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, request, web-worker

```
var Threads = require('webworker-threads');
var request = require('request');

function fibo() {
    request('http://www.google.com', function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            return body;
        }
    })
}
console.log(fibo());

var numThreads = 10;

threadPool = Threads.createPool(numThreads);

threadPool.all.eval(fibo()).all.eval('fibo()', function cb(err, data) {
    process.stdout.write(" [" + this.id + "]" + data + '\n');
    this.eval('fibo()', cb);
});
```

Result of this action will be id of thread and null

```
[123]null
```

How can I wait for this function before continuing?